# Space between the list of figures and the first figure

Tags: floats

I would like to reduce the space between the title figure and the first figure. This is my code:

```
\chapter*{Liste Des Figures}

\renewcommand\listfigurename{}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste Des Figures}

\adjustmtc

\markboth{Liste Des Figures}{}

\listoffigures
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty to translate into English. Let's stick to that …

Comment: One approach is to modify \chapter* (which is used by \listoffigures).  Another is to add negative space using \addtocontents.